# Image upload using codeigniter error

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to make an image upload form in code igniter i am getting the following error.

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: image_file
>
> Filename: controllers/men.php
>
> Line Number: 23
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter-3.1.8\application\controllers\men.php
>   Line: 23 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter-3.1.8\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

## This is my view,controller and model code

1) View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>image</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/public/css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>men/image_upload" id="upload_form" />
            <input type="file" name="image_file">
            <input type="submit" id="upload" name="upload" value="Upload" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

2) Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Men extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view("imageupload");
    }

    public function image_upload(){
        $config['upload_path']='./uploads';
        $config['allowed_types']='*';
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('image_file');
        $image_file = $this->upload->data();
        $data=array('image_file'=> $image_file['image_file']);
        $this->load->model("mymodel");
        $this->mymodel->imagedone($data);   
    }
}
?>
```

3) Model

```
<?php
class Mymodel extends CI_Model{

    function imagedone($data){
        $query = $this->db->insert("image_tbl",$data);
        if($query)
        {
            echo "File is uploaded";
        }
        else{
            echo "failure";
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This error may cause due to missing attribute of form tag, add -> enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in form tag and try like:

`<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>men/image_upload" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
    <input type="file" name="image_file">
    <input type="submit" id="upload" name="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to upload file you need to add enctype attribute to the form.
Add enctype= multipart/form-data attribute to the form and try again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>image</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();? 
 >/public/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
  <body>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url()?>men/image_upload"  
 id="upload_form" />
    <input type="file" name="image_file">
    <input type="submit" id="upload" name="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>

 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: i placed this slash "\" in first form tag may be that is why it wasnt working further

Answer (score 0):

use this attribute in your form
enctype="multipart/form-data"